# VLOOKUP query help required - count from a range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, worksheet-function, countif

I'm trying to build a spreadsheet to help automate points scoring for an office F1 fantasy league we have.

I've attached an example data set, but basically I need to search a range, then count how many times the constructor appears in the numbered positions (discounting R, D as they've not finished), then carry this over to the standings.

I also need to do something similar for the top 10 which says if 2 cars from the same constructor (Mercedes, Mercedes) appear in positions 1-10 then add points to the standings.

In the working model the data for `race1` is direct from the BBC via web query, so how they appear with 'driver' in between is how it must remain (I also have other actions running which lookup the driver info, so can't be moved).

I've popped the [example on my drive here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bylg_zrfhpmbQy1VNF9HWWU4eW8/view?usp=sharing) and [updated version](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bylg_zrfhpmbTnZsdzNkLVNtWlk/view).

Comment: so race1 is the raw data, and standings is where I need to calculate the scores based on the raw data. How many points for 0,1,2 cars finishing is on the standings page. For example 2 cars finished in the top 10 for mercedes, 20 points needs to be awarded in B2. 1 car finished for Caterham, 7 points needs to be awarded for Caterham on the standings page.

Comment: I've amended the example to shop what I have as input and the figures I need to be able to output which I hope makes it clearer: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bylg_zrfhpmbTnZsdzNkLVNtWlk/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be consistent with spellings or this won't work, but for `standings`  B2 you might try:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(race1!C:C,A2,race1!A:A,"<>D",race1!A:A,"<>R")=2,20,IF(COUNTIFS(race1!C:C,A2,race1!A:A,"<>D",race1!A:A,"<>R")=1,7,-15))
```

and in C2:

```
 =COUNTIF(race1!$C$2:$C$11,A2)*10
```

both copied down to suit.

*Edit* for number of cars in column B change first formula to:

```
=COUNTIFS(race1!C:C,A2,race1!A:A,"<>D",race1!A:A,"<>R")
```

and for points put first formula in C2 (copy both down to suit).

Comment: Thanks pnuts. Sorry for the confusing data set :)